# Calling an interrupt handler from kernel mode

Tags: assembly, linux-kernel, x86-64, interrupt, interrupt-handling

Im making a new Interrupt handler for Invalid opcode interupt (x86-64).

As part of the handler, I want to call the original handler, How can I do it?

```
    .globl my_ili_handler

.text
.align 4, 0x90
my_ili_handler:
...
...
...
failed:
  ## call original invalid_op ##
  iretq
```

Comment: If you don't need control back and restored the state to what was upon entry you can just `jmp` to the original handler.

Comment: But what is the name? invalid_op? X86_TRAP_UD? what should i jump to

Comment: How do you install your handler? Either you overwrite the vector, then you know which address you must jump to, or you should get the previous handler address.

Comment: It's `do_invalid_op` but that already takes `(struct pt_regs *regs, long error_code)` so you probably can't jump to it depending on how you installed your handler.

Comment: got the previous adress, thank you